# getting for each questions,number of users that answer correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have case that i need to select for every question number of users that answer that question correct in sql 
my tables look like

```
table 1: questionnaire_question  
id  - question_text - thecorrectAnswer

table 2 :questionnaire_answers  
id -  user_id -  question_id -  user_answer - correct
```

correct column has value  0 or 1 for user answer is correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `LEFT JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

```
select
  q.id,
  count(distinct a.user_id) cnt  -- can be replaced with count(*) 
                                 -- if a user has only at max one correct answer
                                 -- for a given question
from questionnaire_question q
left join questionnaire_answers a
on q.id = a.question_id
where correct = 1
group by q.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join the tables and `count` a `case` expression that checks correctness:

```
SELECT q.id, cnt
FROM   questionnaire_question q
JOIN   (SELECT question_id, COUNT(CASE correct WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS cnt
        FROM   questionnaire_answers
        GROUP BY question_id) a ON q.id = a.question_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery if a question has no correct answer, it will return 0

Try this:

```
SELECT qq.id,
    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM questionnaire_answers qa
    WHERE qa.question_id = qq.question_id
    AND qa.correct = 1), 0)
FROM questionnaire_question qq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select question_id, count(user_id)
from questionnaire_answers
where correct = 1
group by question_id
```

No join needed because you already denormalized the schema by including a correct column.